# Where is the petrified Oni located?

Tags: lore, l5r, l5r-1e, rokugan

I once read about a site in my (now gone) 1st edition of the *Legend of the Five Rings* rulebook. The site is a large rock belived to be a petrified Oni, with an axe lodged into it. I remember that local beliefs said that if the axe is removed the Oni will be restored to flesh and blood.

I'm trying to rediscover what part of Rokugan the site is located in and what the people of Rokugan know the place as. **Where is this rock, and what is it called?**

Comment: If you're looking to re-obtain the 1st edition rules, Drivethru RPG has PDF copies: http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/3564/Legend-of-the-Five-Rings-1st-edition

Answer (score 14):

The place is Masakari Taki, or Broad Axe Waterfall. The large rock with the axe is in the top of said waterfall. It is located in the west area of the phoenix lands, east of the Shrine of the Ki-Rin. The reference can be found in the L5R 1st edition core rulebook, page 240.